# PHP - Export CSV to FTP rather than download in browser

Tags: php, ftp

I have been trying for a few hours now to no avail. I have successfully output my CSV as a download in the browser using:

```
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$csv_filename."");
```

However I want that output to now go to an FTP server instead, I have got the connection and temp file part sorted but cannot seem to edit the file to output my results.

```
// create empty variable to be filled with export data
$csv_export = '';

for($i = 0; $i < $field; $i++) {
$csv_export.= mysql_field_name($query,$i).',';
}
// newline (seems to work both on Linux & Windows servers)
$csv_export.= '
';

// loop through database query and fill export variable
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
// create line with field values
for($i = 0; $i < $field; $i++) {
$csv_export.= '"'.$row[mysql_field_name($query,$i)].'",';
}   
$csv_export.= '
';  
}
```

Above is the part that gets the query data and puts it into the CSV, I have tried incorporating both fputs and fputcsv in the loops to write the rows to the file.

```
//Upload the temporary file to server
ftp_fput($ftpstream, '/httpdocs/.../abandoned.csv', $temp, FTP_ASCII);

$fp = fopen('var/www/vhosts/.../abandoned.csv', 'w');
fputs($fp, '$csv_export');
fclose($fp);
echo($csv_export);
```

So, echoing the output works absolutely fine - all I want is that echo'd data written into a CSV file and uploaded to the FTP.

The error I've been given is:

```
Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, 
boolean given
```

So the fp is causing the problem... is it at the open stage or at the writing of csv_export?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if the script has permission to write to the directory, also enable E_WARNING for displaying the errors returned by fopen()

Comment: Yes, `fopen` might return `FALSE` in case of error.

Comment: No errors from fopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
//Write the contents to the temp file
fputs($temp, $csv_export);

//upload the temp file
ftp_fput($ftpstream, '/httpdocs/.../abandoned.csv', $temp, FTP_ASCII);

//close the temp file
fclose($temp);
```

Your current code is creating an empty file, uploading it, and then creating a separate file.  Even if you get it working on a local server, it is an unnecessary step.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this firstly. Secondly it's throwing me a different error at least. (failed to open stream: Operation not permitted [file] =>). Think this will be the permissions???

Comment: No problem :)  Try deleting the abandoned.csv and then doing it.

Comment: It is working! I got rid of the fopen, which is obviously where my confusion was - I had that open and the temp file!?! As I am a PHP amateur it is my copying and pasting that has obviously confused me, but with your help have got my head round it. THANKS SO MUCH! I wish I could give you some kudos.

Comment: Also, I think you are still supposed to select this one as the answer, sense the comments contained the answer - but I'm new here so I'm not 100% sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not tested:

```
$filename = 'abandoned.csv';
$content  = $csv_export;

$host     = 'yourhost';
$user     = 'youruser'; 
$password = 'yourpass';

//open connection to your ftp server
$stream = stream_context_create(array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => true)));

//authenticate to your ftp server, normal uri syntax
$uri = sprintf('ftp://%s:%s@%s/%s', $user, $password, $host, $filename);
file_put_contents($uri, $content, 0, $stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `phpinfo();` you can look for `Registered PHP Streams` and just use this in most of any cases:

```
file_put_contents('ftp://user:password@server/your/directory/file.csv', $csvData);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ftp_fput` is a right way here.

But you have to prepare FTP connection and authenticate first. Assuming you have `$csv_export` string in memory:

```
// connect
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect('ftp.yourserver.net');

// authenticate
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'ftp_username', 'password');

// prepare output stream
$stream = fopen('data://text/plain,' . $csv_export, 'r');

// try to upload
if (ftp_fput($ftp_conn, '/httpdocs/.../abandoned.csv', $stream, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "Successfully uploaded\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading\n";
}

// close the connection and the file handler
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
fclose($stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving that error because fopen is returning false, which indicates that it was unable to open the file.

If I'm understanding your code, you're uploading abandoned.csv (which presumably exists) to the ftp after opening it in $temp.  Is $temp pointing at your local copy of abandon.csv?  Because if so, you should close the file stream pointing to it before opening a second one with fopen.

If that's not the issue, then abandoned.csv may not actually exist, in which case you may just be trying to fopen a missing file.

Comment: I don't think that is the case - my code for that part is
    $temp = tmpfile();

    //Upload the temporary file to server
    ftp_fput($ftpstream, '/httpdocs/.../abandoned.csv', $temp, FTP_ASCII);

Comment: Ok, well I can tell you that the fopen is your problem - it is returning a boolean false to tell you it's failing.  You most likely don't have permission to write to that directory, or it's possible the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: The file is successfully writing - I did a test by changing filename and it is on the FTP server... However as it is a 0 byte file it clearly is falling over at fopen - any thing you can suggest?

Comment: For clarity, let me ask, are you uploading it via ftp to the same server the script is operating on?

Comment: Basically, it looks like you're writing a temporary file to the ftp server, and then creating a new, completely unrelated file on your current server and writing the actual contents to that.

Also, you will want to lose the quotes around $csv_export, in the fputs call, as the single quotes will turn it into a literal string.

Comment: Yeah, all happening in the same place. It is effectively running the script, querying data and hopefully outputting CSV file to the same folder. In an ideal world! Working perfectly as a download using header operations/

Comment: I gave a new answer down below, hopefully it should fix things :)